# Snapping to vertex outside selected object

Tags: snapping

Modeling a house, say I have to copy lots of the same window to openings all the same size. The modeling of the actual window is slightly complex: frames, grilles, sill etc...
When the time comes to duplicate a complete window to all the wall openings in the house (in object mode), I would like to snap from a vertex at the corner of the wall opening, to a vertex at the corner of the next wall opening, since these are easy to select. This will position the window perfectly... but I can't seem to find the way to snap to points outside the selected object, which is to be duplicated. Snapping to destination vertex outside the selected object is not a problem, but origin...?
Thank You.

[image]

As one can see, the window is tucked further back from the front face of the wall, hence the desired origin and destination points are not on the selected object to be duplicated.

Comment: Add a screenshot.

Comment: Set Snapping to Vertex -> Closest... should do the job.

Comment: I don't know if to answer a reply with 'comment' or 'answer your question'... Anyway, Jan Kadeřábek, Vertex -> Closest is what I've been using. I thank that at the origin point (first snap), this snaps to the closest vertex on the selected object, not the closest vertex to where your cursor is (as in a different object, in this case the wall...)